# Dynamic range to count empty cells

Tags: excel, vba

To define the range for my `For` loop i use a Match function to locate the first row containing a specific string. This works fine and I would like to combine this with the number of empty cells in that Range using the `WorksheetFunction.CountBlank`

I set up this code to return the corresponding row:

```
iCounterFilled01 = 0
On Error Resume Next
iCounterFilled01 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Date", wksSource01.Range("A:A"), 0)
On Error GoTo 0
```

Using this i am trying to return the number of empty cells within this Range

```
iEmptyCells01 = WorksheetFunction.CountBlank_
(wksSource01.Range(wksSource01.Cells(1, 1)), wksSource01.Cells(iCounterFilled01, 8))
```

This however returns the error "incorrect amount of arguments or incorrectly assigned property".

Help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: My guess is that the problem is `wksSource01.Range(wksSource01.Cells(1, 1))`, instead just use `wksSource01.Cells(1, 1)`   Also please explain "does not work"

Comment: @romulax14 i changed the post to reflect the error. Interestingly this works

      Set rngSource01 = wksSource01.Range(wksSource01.Cells(1, 1), wksSource01.Cells(iCounterFilled01, 1))

iEmptyCells01 = WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(rngSource01)

Comment: Ok I found out your error, see answers

Comment: cannot reproduce the problem, but I would advice to narrow down the problem by assigning the range to an intermediate variable. You can then check in the debugger if the range is set correctly before executing the `CountBlank` method

Comment: @Questionairee you had a parenthesis after the Cells(1,1), check your original post, you'll see it.

Comment: @romulax14 thanks! Greatly appreciated! now it works!

Comment: @FunThomas yea, i did that, and it works (see my previous comment) - Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a misplaced parenthesis before the comma inside the parameter of the `CountBlank`, replace this:

```
WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(wksSource01.Range(wksSource01.Cells(1, 1)), wksSource01.Cells(iCounterFilled01, 8))
```

with this

```
WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(wksSource01.Range(wksSource01.Cells(1, 1), wksSource01.Cells(iCounterFilled01, 8)))
```